# How to add new page in not my Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have to insert a new function in a wordpress plugin and I do it with command

```
$bPage = add_submenu_page('hotel_option', __('Block room', 'gdlr-hotel'), __('Block room', 'gdlr-hotel'), 
            'edit_theme_options', 'block-room', 'block_room_option');
        add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'gdlr_transaction_option_style'); 
        add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, 'gdlr_transaction_option_script');
        add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $bPage, 'block_room_style'); 
        add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $bPage, 'block_room_script');
```

But now when I write something like a simple `<div>a</div>`, WP put my div above of WP's upgrade box and when I open the tools for inspection I see that the meta tags are switched from head tag inside body tag, and my `<div>a</div>` appears in every page of wordpress (also in login page)!

How can I solve?
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly write the HTML in main file (plugin's configuration) file, It will show the data in all pages

```
add_submenu_page ( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '' )
```

In this the last parameter is a callback function name

```
// Add to admin_menu function
$page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=theme', __('Theme Page Options'), __('Theme Menu Options'), 'edit_themes', 'theme_options', theme_options);



function theme_options() {
        // do  the stuff of printing here
        // or include a file use include("my_viewpage.php") and write the div and html in this page

}
```

my_viewpage.php needs to be placed in that plugin folder itself

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but also if I include another file, everythings that I write in this file appears above of the upgrade box and the meta tags are inside the body tag